# ¿Como puedo encontrar el coste mínimo es este array de objetos?

Tags: javascript

He probado varias maneras y los resultados son `NaN` o `INFINITY` o simplemente me devuelve todos los números y yo solo quiero el precio menor que seria 90.

No se si estoy usando bien el método `math.min()` o si en un array de objetos es mas complicado.

```js
let flights = [
    { id: 00, to: 'Bilbao', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 1600, scale: false },
    { id: 01, to: 'New York', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 700, scale: false },
    { id: 02, to: 'Los Angeles', from: 'Madrid', cost: 1100, scale: true },
    { id: 03, to: 'Paris', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 210, scale: false },
    { id: 04, to: 'Roma', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 150, scale: false },
    { id: 05, to: 'London', from: 'Madrid', cost: 200, scale: false },
    { id: 06, to: 'Madrid', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 90, scale: false },
    { id: 07, to: 'Tokyo', from: 'Madrid', cost: 1500, scale: true },
    { id: 08, to: 'Shangai', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 800, scale: true },
    { id: 09, to: 'Sydney', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 150, scale: true },
    { id: 10, to: 'Tel-Aviv', from: 'Madrid', cost: 150, scale: false }
];

function minPrice(){
    document.write('<h1>Vuelo con el precio mas bajo</h1>')
    for (let i = 0; i < flights.length; i++){
      let min = Math.min(flights[i].cost);
      document.write(min);
      console.log(min);
    }
    
}

minPrice();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error es que no estas comparando en ningún momento los precios, sino que siempre estas imprimiendo el costo de cada vuelo.

#### Solución:

Usando `for` podrías hacerlo así:

```js
let flights = [
    { id: 00, to: 'Bilbao', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 1600, scale: false },
    { id: 01, to: 'New York', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 700, scale: false },
    { id: 02, to: 'Los Angeles', from: 'Madrid', cost: 1100, scale: true },
    { id: 03, to: 'Paris', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 210, scale: false },
    { id: 04, to: 'Roma', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 150, scale: false },
    { id: 05, to: 'London', from: 'Madrid', cost: 200, scale: false },
    { id: 06, to: 'Madrid', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 90, scale: false },
    { id: 07, to: 'Tokyo', from: 'Madrid', cost: 1500, scale: true },
    { id: 08, to: 'Shangai', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 800, scale: true },
    { id: 09, to: 'Sydney', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 150, scale: true },
    { id: 10, to: 'Tel-Aviv', from: 'Madrid', cost: 150, scale: false }
];

function minPrice(){
  document.write('<h1>Vuelo con el precio mas bajo</h1>');
  let min = Infinity;
  for (let i = 0; i < flights.length; i++){
    // Si el costo es menor al valor mínimo, lo cambiamos
    if (flights[i].cost < min) min = flights[i].cost;
  }
  document.write(min);
}

minPrice();
```

Comment: entonces con el metodo math() no se puede hacer?

Comment: @davidCuenca Si, pero sería mas complicado. Si te fijas a `Math.min` tenes que pasarle cada uno de las opciones por parámetro.

Comment: ok, entendido, visto así es mas sencillo, muchas gracias.